# Rasterize vector layers with different extents into identical raster grids with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, rasterization

I am working on a quite simple spatial potential analysis using QGIS. I have some ArcGIS knowledge, but I am new to QGIS.
My task is to identify the functional inner city of a region based on different criteria like density or distance to public transport. Therefore I created polygon layers representing different criteria. All the polygons have values between 0 and 1. The next step is to rasterize the vector layers and use the raster calculator to make an additions for each raster cell.

The problem I am facing is that the layer extents are different. Therefore all the raster outputs also differ in extent and cell size. As a result I cannot use the raster calculator to make the cell calculations.

So what I need to do, is to find a way to rasterize the polygone layers into raster sets with the same extend and the same cell size. ArcGIs offers the options to set a specific “Analysis extent” and a specific “Analysis cell size” for further raster calculations, which is basically what I am looking for in QGIS. I hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two methods come to mind: You can use the gdal utility, `gdal_rasterize`, with the -a option to specify the attributie column, and the -te and -tr options to set the output extents and resolution the same for each raster. See [details](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) on the GDAL website.

Alternatively, if you work in GRASS, then you first set the desired extents ("region settings"  in GRASS terminology) with `g.region`. Then, when converting the vectors to rasters using `v.to.rast`, that region setting is honored for each new raster.  Here's the [v.to.rast manual page](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.to.rast.html). Almost all GRASS raster modules work within a preset region.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the quick answer. I needed some time to get familiar with qdal and working with a commando line but in the end it worked out. 
it still does not feel like an very intuitive way in comparison to arcgis' userinterface but a solution is better than no solution ;)

Comment: I like your "commando line" typo! As to what is intuitive, everyone has his own intuition...  Now if you need to do a whole batch of vector to raster conversions, you could easily wrap your gdal command into a loop, and do the whole list of critera vectors in one go. I think that might be better than a friendly user interface.