# QGIS proximity raster with extent beyond original coverage?

Tags: qgis, raster, point, distance

I need a raster coverage of distances from points outside the geographic region of interest, and am having trouble doing this with QGIS.

Questions like this one ([Calculating distance to points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis)) seem close to what I want, but I'm getting hung up on the first step.  The raster that I create with the QGIS "Rasterize" tool has an extent that does not overlap with the region of interest (because all of the points I want the distance from are outside of that region).  I don't see any option for changing the extent of the generated raster.

I am then unable to generate a Proximity raster with the extent I need.  How can I get the correct extent?

In addition, when I run "Proximity", I consistently get an error that my raster cells are not square and so distance calculations may not be accurate.  I don't know how to make square cells because the tool asks for how many cells I want in the x and y directions, not the x and y dimensions of each cell.  Is there a way of fixing this?

Ultimately, I'm a bit uncomfortable with the necessity of converting point data to raster in order to calculate proximity, and wonder whether there is an open source tool that can do what I want without the "Rasterize" step...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the first part of my question (how to rasterize with pre-specified extents and resolution) is here: [Rasterize vector layers with different extents into identical raster grids with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62042/rasterize-vector-layers-with-different-extents-into-identical-raster-grids-with?rq=1)

For this purpose, I'm finding working with gdal from the command line more useful than using the QGIS gdal interface.