# Changing raster cell values within polygon using QGIS GUI

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, masking

How do I change the values of raster cells which are within a polygon, leaving all cell values outside the polygon unchanged?

I would like to subtract 1.5m from each raster cell value within the polygon, rather than make them all the same value.

I don't know how to use GRASS so I'm hoping there is a way to do it using the tools within the QGIS GUI, raster calculator, or processing toolbox. I'm using QGIS 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to convert your polygon to a raster. Create an integer field filled with "1" for the purpose of the conversion. (raster > conversion > rasterize)

Then, you can use the raster calculator to substract 1.5 where your polygon exists.

```
 yourdem@1 - ((poltoras@1 = 1) * 1.5 )
```

Comment: thanks.  That method gives me an output raster which is the same extent as the polygon.  I'm hoping to get an output raster the same size as the original DEM. In the output raster's metadata; the layer extent is the same as the original DEM, the max & min values are the original DEM's -1.5m (which is correct) for the area within the polygon, but there are no cells outside the polygon. I set output extent in the Raster Calculator to be the same extent as the original DEM's. Any ideas where I'm going wrong here please?

Comment: well, you could fix the extents according to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62042/rasterize-vector-layers-with-different-extents-into-identical-raster-grids-with, or buiding a virtual raster (Raster ‣ Miscellaneous ‣ Build Virtual Raster (Catalog).) with the required extent, but as you prefer not to go out of the GUI, the workaround is to make a background polygon with the extent of your DEM.

Comment: thank you, I will go with the background polygon method.  What should I do with this background polygon?

Comment: I worked how to use the background polygon.  Thank so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

1. make copy of raster (raster2)
2. Use ***Raster / Conversion / Rasterize***

   - select you polygon layer, make field with -9999 or some value which is not in your raster2
   - as target use your copy raster2 raster/grid
   - Keep existing size and resolution
3. Use ***Raster / Raster Calculator...***

   - expression should be like this:
     ("raster2" = -9999)*("raster1"-1.5) + ("raster2" != -9999)*"raster2"

Answer (score -1):

Or using this Qgis plugin: [ThRasE](https://github.com/SMByC/ThRasE)